# The OpenSSL extension is missing on Windows while installing Composer

Tags: windows, php, openssl, composer

While installing Composer for PHP, I get the following message:

> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You can fix this by recompiling php with the `--with-opensll` option.

Comment: As to what it is. OpenSSL is the part responsive for TLS (think httpS). It is commonly used for secure communications. Originally thi sused something called SSL but those cypers have long since been cracked and these days we use TLS, but the name of the library is unchanged.

Comment: will try then i will tell you the result !

Comment: didn't worked for me !

Answer (score 16):

@RiggsFolly has the right idea.

Additionally I had to:

1. Copy php.ini-development to php.ini
2. Uncomment the `extension=php_openssl.dll` line as described
3. Uncomment this line:
   `extension_dir = "ext"`
4. Make sure you find php_openssl.dll within that extension directory of course

Comment: I was missing Step 1. Thank you for pointing out something so obvious and simple

Comment: Thank you, with a minor tweak: My php.ini was missing the dll section under "Module Settings". Instead, just uncomment "extension=openssl" (without .dll extension) under "Dynamic Extensions".

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed directly from php.net's executable files for windows, the installation has no active `php.ini` file! You can confirm this using `php -ini` command in your console, it says `C:\Windows` which actually has no ini file.

You should first rename one of `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` to `php.ini` and then uncomment the extension. (i.e. removeing semicolon before the  `extension=php_openssl.dll` in that file.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the environment variable, without luck.. I did however try installing the Windows Binary from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and it started working immediately (using Xampp, if that makes a difference..)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is activate the openssl extension in your php.ini by removing the `;` comment from the line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

To

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Warning, there are usually 2 php.ini files, one in the `apache\bin` folder and one in the `\php` folder, edit the one in the `\php\php.ini` folder as this is the one that controls PHP CLI.

Comment: THE SAME ERROR !! :(

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct `php.ini`? There are ususlly 2 you need the one in the php folder and not the one in the apache folder